# C sharp unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

*Could you please help me with writing UnitTest for this method? I tried a couple of ways but I could not solve it.*

```
public ActionResult ChangePass()
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Index", new { area = "" });
    }
}
```

*Here is what I am trying to do.*

```
[TestMethod]
    public void ChangePass()
    {

        var identity = new GenericIdentity("admin@gmail.com");
        var controller = new ProfilePageController();
        var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        var principal = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
       principal.Setup(p => p.IsInRole("user")).Returns(true);
        principal.SetupGet(x => x.Identity.Name).Returns("admin@gmail.com");
        controllerContext.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext.User).Returns(principal.Object);
        controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object;
        NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(controller.ChangePass(), identity.Name);
        }
```

Comment: Please don't ask us to code solutions for you. Post some of your attempts and the specific problem you are having. We'll help you rework a non-working solution to a working solution but not from scratch.

Comment: I post a code of my attempts

Comment: When you run your existing unit test, does it work?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: Can you detail in what way it doesn't work? Does it not compile? Does it give an exception at runtime? Something else?

Comment: Message: Test method Accdatastore.Testing.UnitTestProfilePageController.ChangePass threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

First of all it's a controller action method which shouldn't be unit tested at all. Rather only the business logic should be tested. Why?

cause, look at the line `Request.IsAuthenticated`. at time when you are unit testing there is no `Request` object present and thus that line is bound to throw `NullRefException`.

Moreover your posted action method `ChangePass()` has no business logic involved which to be tested at all

Comment: I know but I want to write test that pass it